# In Linux, how do you delete the partition table from a disk?

Tags: linux, partitioning, mbr, gpt

In Linux, how would I go about removing the GPT or MBR partition table on a disk? To be clear, I don't want to immediately format with a new partition table, I want to be able to remove the partition table completely.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just write some zeros to the first sector of the disk in question, for example you want to erase partition table of sda:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=512 count=1
```

That would fill first 512 bytes of the disk with zeros, and in effect erase the partition table.

Comment: You have the block size and count numbers swapped.

Comment: yeah. but I think either way should work, only bs=512 is better?

Comment: If you're convinced that your original answer is good, then you should have left it alone.